# Class members null after calling class function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory

I have a program with quite a few classes - `MenuRequestHandler`, `LoginRequestHandler`, `RequestHandlerFactory`, etc. In one of my classes, I create a `LoginRequestHandler*` object and a `MenuRequestHandler*` object to use their functions - They both inherit 2 functions from `IRequestHandler`.

The issue is, when I create the `MenuRequestHandler*` object, the members of the object are fine, but after the program proceeds into the object function the members values in the debugger are "Unable to read memory".

```cpp
MenuRequestHandler* menu = m_handlerFactory.createMenuRequestHandler(username);
menu->test();
if (menu->isRequestRelevant(info)) -> this is the function where the object members stop functioning
{ //unrelated code}
```

MenuRequestHandler.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef MENUREQUESTHANDLER_H_
#define MENUREQUESTHANDLER_H_
class RequestHandlerFactory;
class IRequestHandler;
class StatisticsManager;
#include "RequestHandlerFactory.h"
#include "LoggedUser.h"
#include "RoomManager.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "IRequestHandler.h"
#include "StatisticsManager.h"

#include "RequestInfo.h"

class MenuRequestHandler : public IRequestHandler {
private:
    LoggedUser m_user;
    RoomManager& m_roomManager;
    StatisticsManager& m_statisticsManager;
    RequestHandlerFactory& m_handlerFactory;
    std::string booltostring(bool b);
    //A bunch of functions
public:
    MenuRequestHandler(RoomManager roomManager, StatisticsManager statisticsManager, RequestHandlerFactory handlerFactory, std::string username);
    virtual bool isRequestRelevant(RequestInfo requst);
    virtual RequestResult handleRequest(RequestInfo requst);
    void test();
};
#endif
```

It's important to point out that this issue does not occur when using `LoginRequestHandler*` in the same manner. I thought I might have messed something up in the `createMenuRequestHandler()` function, but it's practically the same as the `LoginRequestHandler()` equivalent of it in `RequestHandlerFactory.cpp`:

```cpp
MenuRequestHandler* RequestHandlerFactory::createMenuRequestHandler(std::string username) {
    RoomManager& rManager = m_roomManager;
    StatisticsManager& statManager = m_statisticsManager;
    RequestHandlerFactory& rHandlerFactory = *this;
    std::string newstr = username;
    MenuRequestHandler* handler = new MenuRequestHandler(rManager, statManager, rHandlerFactory, newstr);
    return handler;
}

LoginRequestHandler* RequestHandlerFactory::createLoginRequestHandler() {
    LoginManager& manager = m_loginManager;
    RequestHandlerFactory& rHandlerFactory = *this;
    LoginRequestHandler* loginRequestHandler = new LoginRequestHandler(manager, rHandlerFactory);
    return loginRequestHandler;
}
```

Comment: All too often the point at which a program crashes is unrelated to where the bug actually is. Instead of politely falling over and dying immediately, the program staggers on mortally wounded for a while, sometimes a very long while, before the program shows obvious signs of having been broken. Because of this, unless you already know what the bug was and where it is, it's hard to say what code is or isn't relevant.

Comment: The `MenuRequestHandler` constructor parameters are passed by value (copy) and I assume you assign those values to the reference members in the class. It would seem those references are left dangling as soon as the constructor ends and the parameter values are destroyed.

Comment: When you fix the above, also consider turning on whatever [sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers) your development tools support to help you track down other unseen issues in the code.  If none are supported, at least jack up the compiler's warning level and resolve all of the warnings. Unrelated: consider returning `std::unique_ptr`s. It won't help you here, but could save your bacon later.

Answer (score 1):

Aight so apparently the constructor for MenuRequestHandler was NOT receiving references as arguments when the object members themselves were references, and so the parameter values from the references were destroyed. It is 3:45am where I live and I can finally go to sleep, thanks for all the helpful comments :)